# Can not use serverSideTranslations on Vercel

Tags: next.js, netlify, vercel, next-i18next

In my index page i'm using `serverSideTranslations` function. getting error about finding file of translation.
this error happens only on pages that used by `serverSideTranslations`.

I deployed to Vercel and Netlify. in both of them i'v got the same error.

in `_app.js` i'm using `appWithTranslation`.

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@netlify/plugin-nextjs": "^3.9.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "is-mobile": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "^11.1.2",
    "next-i18next": "^8.9.0",
    "next-seo": "^4.20.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "parse": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "^1.2.4",
    "recoil": "^0.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.43.2",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  }
```

next.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const { PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER } = require('next/constants')
const i18NextConfig = require('./next-i18next.config');

const prodConfig = {
    generateBuildId: () => 'build-id',
    compress: true,
    target: 'serverless',
    i18n: i18NextConfig.i18n,
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
    },
}
module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
    if (phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER) {
        return {
            ...defaultConfig,
            ...prodConfig,
            compress: false,
        }
    }

    return prodConfig;
}
```

next-i18next.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'he',
    locales: ['he'],
    localePath: path.resolve('./locales'), // <<< i tried to put this line here
  },
  keySeparator: '>',
  nsSeparator: '|',
  reloadOnPrerender: false,
  localePath: path.resolve('./locales'), // <<< and also here
};
```

### Error message from Vercel lambda function

ng request: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/var/task/public/locales/he'
at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:1043:3)
at getLocaleNamespaces (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:175:23)
at /var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:181:20
at Array.map ()
at getNamespaces (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:180:44)
at createConfig (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/config/createConfig.js:221:29)
at _callee$ (/var/task/node_modules/next-i18next/dist/commonjs/serverSideTranslations.js:199:53)
at tryCatch (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
at Generator.next (/var/task/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21) {
errno: -2,
syscall: 'scandir',
path: '/var/task/public/locales/he'
}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should modify next-i18next.config.js file in your project, and add path.resolve to locale path. You can see an example in [this](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next-vercel) repo. Make sure that you know where your locale folder is located, and write the correct path.
The answer to this issue was found in [this](https://github.com/isaachinman/next-i18next/issues/462#issuecomment-716206904) github thread.

Comment: There's usually no problem with getStaticProps as shown in the repo. What was (and still is) a problem is the behaviour with getServerSideProps - that was when things really go haywire. - The problem being locales are not included in the bundle. I am currently investigating on how to force Vercel to bundle those files...

Answer (score 10):

#### Note(Vercel and Netlify)

Some serverless PaaS may not be able to locate the path of your translations and require additional configuration. If you have filesystem issues using `serverSideTranslations`, set `config.localePath` to use `path.resolve`.

#### Solution

You have to set `config.localePath` into the `next-i18next.config.js` file.

For example,

```js
// next-i18next.config.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  },
  // Path to the translation files
  // i.e., ./public/locales/en.json, ./public/locales/fr.json
  localePath: path.resolve("./public/locales"),
}
```

For more information please refer to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-i18next#:%7E:text=Some%20serverless%20PaaS%20may%20not%20be%20able%20to%20locate%20the%20path%20of%20your%20translations%20and%20require%20additional%20configuration.%20If%20you%20have%20filesystem%20issues%20using%20serverSideTranslations%2C%20set%20config.localePath%20to%20use%20path.resolve).